# How to format date in java logging?

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I am using :

```
log.info("Message");
```

and the output is:

```
Jul 8, 2014 12:58:02 PM myclass main
INFO: message
```

How do i just print the message without the date and INFO: ?

Comment: which logging framework

Comment: Sounds like you just need to configure logging appropriately. Read http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/configuration.html or another similar tutorial... If you still have problems, post what you've tried and what went wrong.

Comment: If the extra info always has the same format, you could split the string where the Message connects to the INFO and just print the Message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the format of the [SimpleFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html) using the system property:

```
-Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format="%2$s: %5$s%6$s%n"
```

or in the [logging.properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html):

```
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%2$s: %5$s%6$s%n
```

All of these properties are documented in the [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format-java.util.logging.LogRecord-) method.