# How can I set the locale used by java.util.logging.Formatter?

Tags: java, android, locale, java.util.logging

I'm using `java.util.logging` in Android because I need to log to other outputs than the system logs. At the moment I'm using a [`java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html). When it logs to a file, it formats the date and timestamp using a default locale, which in my case makes it difficult to read (non-European numerals, complicated use case, long story).

In [`java.util.Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) (as opposed to [`java.util.logging.Formatter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/Formatter.html)),  you can supply a Locale argument to the constructor, so you can specify the ROOT locale if you want:

```
Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb, Locale.ROOT);
```

(In a similar way you can pass a locale argument to [`String.format()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)).) But `java.util.logging.Formatter` and its descendants don't seem to have any way to specify the locale used.

I could extend `Formatter` or `SimpleFormatter` and override `format()` or `formatMessage()`, but I don't see any hooks in there for formatting just the date/time stamp, so I'd have to rewrite the functionality of formatting the whole LogRecord. That's probably not too bad, but it's a lot less optimal (and more error-prone) than supplying a locale.

My current strategy is to copy-and-modify the code for [SimpleFormatter.format()](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.java/?v=source), but of course that cuts the app off from future fixes to that method.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the [format of the `SimpleFormatter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637600/how-to-format-date-in-java-logging/24638736#24638736) to any [pattern supported by the `java.util.Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).  As you point out, the [`Locale.getDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault--) is always used by the `SimpleFormatter` to format log records.

Try using the [`java.util.Locale.setDefault​(Locale.Category, Locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault-java.util.Locale.Category-java.util.Locale-) to set the format category to `Locale.ROOT`.  For example:

```
java.util.Locale.setDefault​(Locale.Category.FORMAT, Locale.ROOT);
```

Otherwise, you have to try to format individual parts of the date as described in [java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format-java.util.logging.LogRecord-) documentation:

> java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format="%1$tb %1$td, %1$tY %1$tl:%1$tM:%1$tS %1$Tp %2$s%n%4$s: %5$s%n"

**Disclaimer:** I'm a content developer for [`com.sun.mail.util.logging`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/util/logging/package-frame.html) included with JavaMail project.  If you use the [`com.sun.mail.util.logging.CompactFormatter`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/util/logging/CompactFormatter.html) it chooses the [locale of the resource bundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getLocale--) assigned to the log record.  If you are not using localization then [null is used as the default locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.util.Locale-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) which should be the same as the ROOT.

As a last resort you'll have to roll your own or find a 3rd party lib.

Comment: Thanks, changing the default locale is a good idea for how to make SimpleFormatter use the locale I want. However, in this case, setting the default locale would risk ripple effects that I don't want to happen, such as changing the current layout direction.

Comment: @LarsH It might be time to file a RFE against OpenJDK to improve the locale handling in logging.  I really think it should use the locale of the resource bundle but, allowing the user to choose the locale as a logging property is a good idea too.  If you have access to JavaMail you might be able to use the CompactFormatter with a custom pattern.