# Remove part of custom log handler

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I am currently working on a program and I set up custom log handlers.
My log handler looks like this:

```
public class ProxyLogFormat extends Formatter {

    // Create a DateFormat to format the logger timestamp.
    private static final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss.SSS");

    public String format(LogRecord record) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(1000);
        builder.append(df.format(new Date(record.getMillis()))).append(" - ");
        builder.append("[").append(record.getLoggerName()).append("] -");
        builder.append("[").append(record.getLevel()).append("] - ");
        builder.append(formatMessage(record));
        builder.append("\n");
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public String getHead(Handler h) {
        return super.getHead(h);
    }

    public String getTail(Handler h) {
        return super.getTail(h);
    }
}
```

I register the log handler like this:

```
   Handler CH = new ConsoleHandler();
    CH.setFormatter(new ProxyLogFormat());
    log.addHandler(CH);
```

(log being a Logger object)
However, aginest all my trys, the log looks like this:

```
10:31:21.249 - [MAIN] -[INFO] - Starting proxy...
May 11, 2018 10:31:21 PM pw.mmvyoutube.proxycrack.Main main
INFO: Starting proxy...
10:31:21.265 - [MAIN] -[INFO] - Host: 0.0.0.0
May 11, 2018 10:31:21 PM pw.mmvyoutube.proxycrack.Main main
INFO: Host: 0.0.0.0
10:31:21.266 - [MAIN] -[INFO] - Remote Port: 111
May 11, 2018 10:31:21 PM pw.mmvyoutube.proxycrack.Main main
INFO: Remote Port: 111
10:31:21.268 - [MAIN] -[INFO] - Local Port: 100
May 11, 2018 10:31:21 PM pw.mmvyoutube.proxycrack.Main main
INFO: Local Port: 100
```

As you can see, some messages repeat and it still has the annoying `May 11, 2018 10:31:21 PM pw.mmvyoutube.proxycrack.Main main`
How can I remove this line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple [ConsoleHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/logging/ConsoleHandler.html) objects installed in the logger tree.  You need to locate those extra handlers and remove them.

You have a few options:

1. You could invoke [`LogManager.reset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#reset()) before you install your console handler. This will remove all installed handlers in the logger tree.
2. Don't create a new ConsoleHandler and simply change the format of the default ConsoleHandler.  For example

   `for (Handler h : Logger.getLogger("").getHandlers()) {
       if(h instanceof ConsoleHandler) {
           h.setFormatter(new ProxyLogFormat());
       }
   }`
3. Avoid using code to setup your logger tree and use a [logging.properties file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html). Using that file you can change the default formatter.
4. Edit the default format pattern of the [SimpleFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format(java.util.logging.LogRecord)).  This can be specified using the `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format` key in the [logging.properties or as a system property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637600/how-to-format-date-in-java-logging/24638736#24638736).  Your pattern is `%1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS.%1$tL - [%3$s] -[%4$s] %5$s%n`