# How can I change the date format for Google's Flogger (fluent logging API for Java)?

Tags: java, logging, lombok, java.util.logging

I'm trying the Lombok @Flogger feature which is supposed to add the below when annotating the class with @Flogger.

```
private static final com.google.common.flogger.FluentLogger log = com.google.common.flogger.FluentLogger.forEnclosingClass();
```

See the little documentation on it. https://projectlombok.org/features/log

I added the below log to a method:

```
log.atInfo().log("This is my info message");
```

And the output that I see in the console is:

```
Mar 21, 2019 7:35:05 PM net.domain.Class myMethod
INFO: This is my info message
```

I'd prefer a "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.mmm" with 24-hour time format.  Is there way to configure this?  I don't have to use the Lombok annotation, it just seemed simpler.

Also, I wasn't able to find the flogger tag for this post.

Comment: Also, see the Google Flogger documentation and github links https://google.github.io/flogger/ and https://github.com/google/flogger

Answer (score 1):

From the output it looks like [flogger](https://github.com/google/flogger/issues/33) is using [SimpleFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html) from JUL.   The format is controlled by setting the [system property or define the key in the logging.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637600/how-to-format-date-in-java-logging/24638736#24638736). The formatter arguments are described in [SimpleFormatter::format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format(java.util.logging.LogRecord)) method.  Keep in mind that the arguments in the documentation are off by one so the date parameter is actually `%1`.

The syntax of the date formatting is described in [java.util.Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Here is [sample test program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532155/simpleformatter-ignoring-the-java-util-logging-simpleformatter-format-property) that can used to make sure your pattern compiles correctly when applied at runtime.  One pattern that should work is: `%1$tF %1$tT.%1$tL %2$s%n%4$s: %5$s%6$s%n`.

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String format = "%1$tF %1$tT.%1$tL %2$s%n%4$s: %5$s%6$s%n";
        final String key = "java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format";
        test(format);
        test(System.getProperty(key, format));
        test(LogManager.getLogManager().getProperty(key));
    }

    private static void test(String format) {
        if (format != null) {
            LogRecord record = new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "");
            System.out.println(String.format(format,
                             new java.util.Date(record.getMillis()),
                             record.getSourceClassName(),
                             record.getLoggerName(),
                             record.getLevel().getLocalizedName(),
                             record.getMessage(),
                             String.valueOf(record.getThrown())));
        } else {
            System.out.println("null format");
        }
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
2019-03-21 21:51:08.604 null
INFO: null
```