# Flogger [google] how to config log format and log file

Tags: java, logging

I wanted to log exception into log file instead of console.
How to configure Flogger logging.

```
package renameform;
import com.google.common.flogger.FluentLogger;

public class TestFlogger {
    private static final FluentLogger logger = FluentLogger.forEnclosingClass();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int a=2/0;
        }catch(Exception exception)
        {
            logger.atInfo().withCause(exception).log("Log message with: %s", 200);
        }   

    }

}
```

output:

```
May 30, 2019 2:16:00 PM renameform.TestFlogger main
INFO: Log message with: 200
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at renameform.TestFlogger.main(TestFlogger.java:8)
```

need so info about logs into text file & how to format.

Answer (score 1):

From the output it looks like [flogger](https://github.com/google/flogger/issues/33) is using [SimpleFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html) from JUL.   The format is controlled by setting the [system property or define the key in the logging.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637600/how-to-format-date-in-java-logging/24638736#24638736). The formatter arguments are described in [SimpleFormatter::format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format(java.util.logging.LogRecord)) method.  Keep in mind that the arguments in the documentation are off by one so the date parameter is actually `%1`.
The syntax of the date formatting is described in [java.util.Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

You can reference [Java Logging - how to redirect output to a custom log file for a logger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248899/java-logging-how-to-redirect-output-to-a-custom-log-file-for-a-logger) as an example on configuring a FileHandler.  The configuration file is explained in [Java Logging Overview](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html#a1.8).